# Помогите пожалуйста с реализацией yii2 меню widget

Tags: yii2

Вот html код менюшки:

```
                                <ul id="m_nav_list" class="m_nav menu__list">
                                    <li class="m_nav_item active" id="m_nav_item_1"> <a href="index.html" class="link link--kumya"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span data-letters="Home">Home</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="m_nav_item" id="moble_nav_item_2"> <a href="typography.html" class="link link--kumya scroll"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span data-letters="Services">Services</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="m_nav_item" id="moble_nav_item_3"> <a href="blog.html" class="link link--kumya scroll"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><span data-letters="Blog">Blog</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="m_nav_item" id="moble_nav_item_5"> <a href="gallery.html" class="link link--kumya scroll"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span data-letters="Gallery">Gallery</span></a></li>
                                    <li class="m_nav_item" id="moble_nav_item_6"> <a href="contact.html" class="link link--kumya scroll"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span data-letters="Contact Us">Contact Us</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
```

К сожалению не сработали все стили ссылок, а вот и сам код:

```
<?php


NavBar::begin([

'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,

    'options' => [

    'class' => ' ',
    ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([

  'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav menu__list',

  'id' => ['m_nav_list'
  ],
 'items' => [

  ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index'],

   'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav_item active',

   'id' => ['m_nav_item_1'],

   'template' => '<a href = "{url}" class = "link link--kumya"><i class = "fa fa-home" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span data-letters = "Home"></span>{label}</a>',
 ],                                                                         
 ['label' => 'Services', 'url' => ['/site/typography'],

  'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav_item',

  'id' => ['moble_nav_item_2'],

  'template' => '<a href = "{url}" class = "link link--kumya scroll"><i class = "fa fa-cog" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span data-letters = "Services"></span>{label}</a>',
  ],

 ['label' => 'Blog', 'url' => ['/site/blog'],

  'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav_item',

  'id' => ['moble_nav_item_3'],

  'template' => '<a href = "{url}" class = "link link--kumya scroll"><i class = "fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span data-letters = "Blog"></span>{label}</a>',
  ],

['label' => 'Gallery', 'url' => ['/site/gallery'],

  'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav_item',

  'id' => ['moble_nav_item_5'],

  'template' => '<a href = "{url}" class = "link link--kumya scroll"><i class = "fa fa-homepicture-o" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span data-letters = "Gallery"></span>{label}</a>',
  ],

['label' => 'Contact Us', 'url' => ['/site/contact'],

  'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav_item',

  'id' => ['moble_nav_item_6'],

  'template' => '<a href = "{url}" class = "link link--kumya scroll"><i class = "fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden = "true"></i><span data-letters = "Comtact Us"></span>{label}</a>',
  ],

NavBar::end();
?>
```

А точнее не сработали 'template' => ...
Что я не так прописала?

Comment: Покажите код Ваших попыток, и что у Вас не получается, тут не фриланс сайт

Comment: У Вас код вообще не верен. Куча ошибок. В Nav нет такого параметра, как "template".
Приведите свой код в нормальный вид.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро.
Вы бы внимательней документацию читали бы. 
Вот Вам пример, как надо оформить пункты меню в Nav. Привожу пример только одного пункта, остальные сделайте самостоятельно, по моему примеру.

```
NavBar::begin([
   'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
   'options' => [
       'class' => ' ',
   ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
'id' => 'm_nav_list',
'options' => ['class' => 'm_nav menu__list'],
'encodeLabels' => false,
'items' => [

    [
        'label' => "<i class='fa fa-home' aria-hidden='true'></i><span data-letters = 'Home'>Home</span>",
        'url' => ['/site/index'],
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'm_nav_item active',
            'id' => 'm_nav_item_1',
        ],
        'linkOptions' => [
            'class' => 'link link--kumya',
        ]
    ]
    /* следующие пункты меню... */
  ]
])

NavBar::end();
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста. Используйте редактор с подсветкой кода и парных тегов/скобок/кавычек и читайте внимательней документацию.